# How to limit number of instalments in PayPal Subscription?

Tags: php, paypal-subscriptions

I'm creating subscription with API just fine using this tutorial

> https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/subscriptions/v1/#subscriptions_create

When I create a Plan, I can set `total_cycles`, like so

```
  "tenure_type": "REGULAR",
  "sequence": 2,
  "total_cycles": 12,
```

BUT when it comes to customer to "Agree and Subscribe" the subscription details says:

[image]

My problem is that I don't want it to be "Automatic renewal until you cancel". I want it to stop after the set number of instalments.

How can I do it?

I find in documentation that `auto_renewal` option is `DEPRECATED`. Quote:

> auto_renewal boolean
>
> DEPRECATED. Indicates whether the subscription auto-renews after the billing cycles complete.

What other options do I have?

Answer (score 0):

to late but actually faced this today, use total_cycles = 0 , since auto_renewable is deprecated

```
        {
      "frequency": {
        "interval_unit": "MONTH",
        "interval_count": 1
      },
      "tenure_type": "REGULAR",
      "sequence": 1,
      "total_cycles": 0,
      "pricing_scheme": {
        "fixed_price": {
          "value": "XXXX",
          "currency_code": "EUR"
        }
      }
    }
```

Comment: I'm sorry, but if you set "total_cycles" = 0 it would mean "indefinite" number of cycles. I wanted the other way, I waned it to be "finite" and "not renewable".

Comment: I talked this problem over with the PayPal support. They have a bug. The message "Automatic renewal until you cancel" should not be shown because in reality it will not be renewed. That is what they said. I'm not sure if they fixed this bug, they said it was not critical because it does not affect the functionality, it is only a misleading message :). And they closed my ticket without resolution and they said that they will not notify me when it is done. It was rude on their end, but what I could do?